# VeeValidate infinite args

Tags: validation, vue.js, vee-validate

I am trying to make VeeValidate 3 infinite args rule work:
https://logaretm.github.io/vee-validate/guide/basics.html#rule-arguments

Here is the code :

```
 const aValidationFunction(value, values) {
  //iterations and business here
}

extend('my_rule', {
   validation : aValidationFunction,
   computesRequired : true,
   immediate : true,
   // message etc.....
})
```

My rule usage im my code :
Child Component

```
<ValidatedInput  name="inputA"
                         :label="this.$t('XXXX.yyy')"
                         :iid="'inputA'"
                         type="text"
                         :rules="myRulesA"
                         :immediate="true"
                         v-model="XXXX.yyyy">
</ValidatedInput>
<ValidatedInput  name="inputB"
                         :label="this.$t('XXXXX.zzzzz')"
                         :rules="myRulesB"
                         :iid="'inputB'"
                         type="text"
                         :immediate="true"
                         v-model="XXXX.zzzzz">
 </ValidatedInput>

    export default {
      name: 'ChildComponent',
      components: { ValidatedInput },
      props: ['myRulesA', 'myRulesB'], ...........
```

Father component

```
<ValidationObserver>
  <ChildComponent  :my-rules-A="rulesA" :my-rules-A="rulesB" />
  ............
</ValidationObserver>

computed : {
rulesA() {
  return { my_rule: ['@inputB', '@anotherInputBBB'], another_rule: ['@anotherInputA', '@anotherInputB'] //a rule with two args, it works};
},
rulesB() {
  return {my_rule: ['@inputA', '@anotherInputAAAAA']};
},
```

but if i put `console.log(values)` in my code `aValidationFunction` it prints me `['@inputA', '@inputB']`

Any idea ?

Comment: It seems like you've implemented "infinite args" just fine, but that your issue is with cross-field validation working?  In order to help with that, we'd need to see the relevant template (i.e. what does the form look like?)

Comment: Edit done, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Targeting other fields in cross field validations doesn't work with infinite parameters.
https://github.com/logaretm/vee-validate/issues/2839#issue-667100530